# Matching Similar but not same columns

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables say `A` and `B`. I need to updated `state` column in `A` based on `city` in `B`.
`B` has got actual lookup data

`A` and `B` has another column `City`.
`City` in `A` is kind of junk data like Atlanta,Atlanta Georgia,Atlanta-Georgia,Atlanta,Georgia
etc 
`City` in `B` is just Atlanta.
I need to compare both the cities and update `state` in `A`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT b.state FROM A, B WHERE INSTR(A.city ,TRIM(UPPER(B.CITY))) >0
```

The above select select most of them but not some of them. Can someone help me out please.

Thanks

Comment: Is case sensitivity enabled? Perhaps both cities need to be uppered or lowered. and perhaps a trim needs to occur on A.City.

Comment: What are the specific values that it is not capturing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please list some examples that are left out from above SQL. Thanks.
Secondly, try soundex function. See if that works.

Cheers
V